# React Select abreviate dropdown names on multi select

Tags: javascript, reactjs, select, react-select

Hi is it possible to abbreviate dropdown names when selected like the figure below
[image]

this is my code :

```
          multiValue: [
            { value: "BUF", label: "BUF" },
            { value: "CCT", label: "CCT" },
            { value: "JHB", label: "JHB" },
            { value: "EKH", label: "EKH" },
            { value: "ETK", label: "ETK" },
            { value: "MAN", label: "MAN" },
            { value: "NMB", label: "NMB" },
            { value: "TSH", label: "TSH" }
          ],
```

```
      handleMultiChange(option) {
        this.setState({multiValue: option}); 
}
```

```
                  <Select
                    id='multiple'
                    name="filters"
                    placeholder="Filter City"
                    value={this.state.multiValue}
                    options={this.state.filterOptions}
                    onChange={this.handleMultiChange}
                    isMulti={this.state.isMulti}
                    styles={style}
                  />
```

Answer (score 2):

You could accomplish this by providing a custom MultiValueLabel component

MultiValueLabel.component.js

```js
export default function MultiValueLabel({
  data,
  innerProps,
  selectProps
}) {
  // ...any logic you might need
  // 'data' should be the full object of each selected item
  // so reference whatever key is necessary
  return (
    <div {...innerProps}>
      {data.abbr}
    </div>
  )
}
```

Then you just pass that in

```
<Select
  components={{
    MultiValueLabel
  }}
  ... other props
/>
```

Comment: Do you mean `<Select
  components={{
    Multi*Value*Label
  }}
  ... other props
/>` ?